# Apache vs Meta tags for specific IE Mode emulation?

Tags: apache, internet-explorer

I have seen two popular options to force IE to open an HTML in a particular mode:

1) `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

2) Specify it as a Header in `httpd.conf`

What are the advantages of either of these options? Is there a recommended approach to do this?

Most applications I have seen use Apache as a load balancer and it usually handles a request to `www.url.com` and sends it to one of possible application servers. Here anyway accessing the IP directly would not get the benefit of emulation because no Headers are set. Meta tag solves the problem closer than Apache does? So isn't that the better way to set a specific emulation or does Apache approach have other benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither to be honest.

X-UA-Compatible is no longer supported (as of IE11 and above) and [Microsoft recommends not using it and instead using the HTML5 doc type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx).

Saying that, to answer your question (in case interested in other headers like this), it depends. There are benefits to both.

Benefits of setting HTTP Headers

- Can be set once at server level and don't need to remember to include on every page.
- Useful if you don't have control over all the pages (e.g. many developers/contributors upload content to the site).
- HTTP Header usually takes precedence (though not with X-UA-Compatible).

Benefits of setting at page level:

- Doesn't require access to server (e.g. If page is hosted on a server where you don't have access to server config, or served across CDN).
- Will be copied when page us served over CDN or other caching solution.
- Can be set by page author (e.g. if page requires a specific header and author knows this).
- It's usually easier to override per page if you need different settings per page rather than loading all that config in Apache.

Comment: Mostly we use SPA, so I feel that `meta` is the better option. However will checkout `doctype`

Comment: X-UA-Compatible is deprecated in IE11, but is still supported.

Answer (score 1):

When an individual page contains an x-ua-compatible header, [it overrides headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx) provided by the server.  There are times this is useful (for serving legacy websites that do not have DOCTYPE directives) and times when it's not.  Usually, you know which situation you're by the problems you're trying to resolve.

The recommended practice is to [use an HTML5 doctype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699338(v=vs.85).aspx) (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) for most situations and to only use x-ua-compatible for legacy sites that rely on legacy markup.  Ideally, this would be a [temporary solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986087(v=vs.85).aspx) used only until a new version of the site has been developed so that it no longer relies on the legacy behavior.